# XNA 4.0 OutOfMemory Exception spriteBatch

Tags: c#, exception, xna, monogame, radix

I'm creating a brickbreaker on Visual Studio 2017 with XNA 4.0, but I have a problem : an OutOfMemory Exception in the LoadContent() method, when I create spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice). [Here is the location of the error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHBx1.png)

Thanks for your help.

Edit : Here are the references of the method

[image]

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code and the exception you're getting? Please read [ask]

Comment: Where do you define the LoadContent()? Because I notice they're referenced twice. Avoid calling the LoadContent() in the Update() or Draw() methods unless they'll only be called once.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for your answer. LoadContent() in my class Balle is referenced in two others classes which are component game, in their own LoadContent() methods, but not in my Update() and Draw() methods.

Comment: Hi Vincent, please keep in mind that it's better to edit your question rather than posting it as an answer, else it can be assumed the question is answerred. I would probably need more information on how often it goes through the loadContent, perhaps you could try debugging it through.

Comment: @Steven It goes through the loadContent only one time and thrown the exception, and after it goes on the other loadContent of the other game component. With debugger, I saw that I had an error with an object of my class Balle (where is the LoadContent() which thrown exception) "uneballe.GraphicsDevice" which thrown an exception "System.InvalidOperationException", may is it linked?